# How to declare an Angular directive using "this"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, this

I have the following code:
http://jsbin.com/seveba/1/edit

Or for a TL;DR

```
app.directive("enter", function() {
    return function(scope, element) {
        element.bind("mouseenter", function() {
            console.log("I'm inside of you!");
        });
    };
});
```

I Understand the main logic behind this, but I recall learning how to write directives like this:

```
app.directive('directiveName', function() {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // directive code goes here
    }
});
```

is the code on egghead good to use? I know the link function is executed after the angular compiles the dom, but this doesn't help me clear up which way is better. Also, I've started to use the controller as syntax which made me stop using $scope on controllers to assign variables to the object via "this". Can I also do that with directives? Or are they completely different things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking more for something like this

```
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'SomeController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    template: '{{ctrl.foo}}'
    link: function(){}
  };
```

either way from your question is good to declare directive, i prefer to return object which is more readable and self explanatory for someone whi is going to touch code after me

Comment: Wasn't the link function prefered for giving interactivity to dom elements? I tought angular controllers weren't meant for dom manipulation (which is what I'm using mine for). Also, can explain how this will play with my controllers using "this" to add properties to the scope? It seems weird to inject scope into a directive when I've stopped using it on my controllers.

Comment: i missed the link function but it's still available, `link` happens postcompali, `controller` is precompile

Answer (score 0):

```
The below syntax would be proper for creating a generic directive.
```

to implement :

```
<div directive-name></div>
```

Code:

```
app.directive('directiveName', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

          elem.bind('click', function() {
          alert("clicked!");
     });
   }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Can you explain me how this would play along with the controller "this" property declaration? Or would it be the same? I tought the "this" way of adding properties to the scope was a way to stop using the scope variable, but naming it as this.